# Redshift Error when adding date to a time stamp using case statement

Tags: case, amazon-redshift

I am trying to have a CASE statement that adds days to a time stamp column.

```
select cust_id, 
case when type = 'a' then (created_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY')
when type = 'b' then (created_date - INTERVAL '10 DAY') 
else 0 end as date_when_breach 
from table
```

The above throws an error

```
Reason:
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: CASE types integer and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched
```

Sample created_date value is `2019-02-14 11:16:16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` statement is not consistent with return types - first two branches return a `DATE` and the `ELSE` returns an `INTEGER`. Change your `ELSE` to return `DATE` (eg.`current_date`, depends on what you want to achieve) or `NULL` (or just remove it, which will have the same effect).

```
select 
  cust_id, 
  case 
     when type = 'a' then (created_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY')
     when type = 'b' then (created_date - INTERVAL '10 DAY') 
     else NULL 
  end as date_when_breach 
from table
```